# The web application does not utilize HTTPonly cookies

Tags: http, iis, cookies, browser, xss

How to avoid Cross-Site scripting attack by not
allowing cookies with the HTTPonly attribute to be accessed via client-side scripts.
I am using ASP.NET 3.5, IIS 8 and IE9 browser. (It should provide security for all web browser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After surfing many sites, I found a solution for this question:

> This is a new security feature introduced by Microsoft in IE 6 SP1 to mitigate the possibility of a successful Cross-Site scripting attack by not allowing cookies with the HTTPonly attribute to be accessed via client-side scripts.

Recommendations include adopting a development policy that includes the utilization of HTTP only cookies, and performing other actions such as ensuring proper filtration of user-supplied data, utilizing client-side validation of user supplied data, and encoding all user supplied data to prevent inserted scripts being sent to end users in a format that can be executed.

**regarding secure cookies add below line**
**under web.config file**

```
 <system.web>
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true"  requireSSL="false" />
 <system.web>
```

- requireSSL="true" if you are using https for http keep it false.

[Find more details here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/workshop/author/dhtml/httponly_cookies.asp)